# Startup disk creator won't add new files

Tags: live-usb

I attempted to use the startup disk creator to write an image to an SD card for my Raspberry Pi. So now when I try to use the startup disk creator, the path to the source of the image/ISO file is still set to the image for the Pi. When I attempt to change it and queue the Ubuntu ISO to write to my flash drive, it won't set and it is stuck on the path to the image for the Pi. I've remove the program and re-installed it to no effect. Am I missing something? How do I clear the settings and truly have a fresh install of the startup disk creator.

Thanks

Comment: You can also try `unetbootin` for this porpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`sudo apt-get purge startup-disk-creator`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get install startup-disk-creator`